# Plesk hosted wordpress site only partially loading assets JS and CSS files returning a 404 cant load and net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, plesk

I am working on a small demo for a website migration to wordpress for updating materials. I have been able to successfully install wordpress onto the plesk hosting server and tie it to my subdomain. The front end does not load the css or js files though, and returns the following error:

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I also am only able to partially use the admin page because the same error occurs. It appears that all wp-admin, wp-content, and wp-includes files are not loading. I have double checked that all folders and files have the appropriate permissions. I still receive a 404 error for the js and css files. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Solutions previously tried with no success:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-status-for-css-and-js-files/
https://www.kickstartcommerce.com/fix-wordpress-failed-load-resource-404-status-error.html
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013561359-Errors-404-on-websites-for-some-JS-CSS-images-and-PHP-files-